# You toss a fair die three times. What is the expected value of the largest of the three outcomes?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, order-statistics

In fact, I do not really get the question first.

You toss a fair die three times. What is the expected value of the largest of the three outcomes?

"expected value of the largest of the three outcomes"

Can anyone clarify this part and give me some ideas?

Comment: It probably just means EV of the largest order statistic. So what is the expected value of the die that rolled the highest number.

Comment: Let us put it in terms of money. You toss the die three times. The amount of money you get is the largest number showing. So for example if you get $5,3,5$ or $1,5,2$ you win $5$ dollars.   What is the expected amount of money you get?

Comment: One approach to a solution is to let random variable $X$ be the amount of money you win. Find $\Pr(X=1)$, $\Pr(X=2)$, and so on up to $\Pr(X=6)$, and then find $E(X)$ in the usual way.

Answer (score 5):

Consider three random variables, $X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$, where $X_i$ gives the value of the $i$:th die roll and these random variables are independent with uniform distribution on the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. The largest of the three outcomes is the random variable $\max\{X_1,X_2,X_3\}$. By independence of the random variables we have
\begin{align*}
P(\max\{X_1,X_2,X_3\}\leq n)=P(X_1,X_2,X_3\leq n)=P(X_1 \leq x)P(X_2\leq x)P(X_3\leq n)=\frac{n^{3}}{6^{3}}.
\end{align*}
So
\begin{align*}
E(\max\{X_1,X_2,X_3\})&=\sum_{n=0}^{5}P(\max\{X_1,X_2,X_3\}>n) \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{5}(1-\frac{n^{3}}{6^{3}})\\
&=6-\sum_{n=0}^{5}\frac{n^{3}}{6^{3}}\\
&=6-\frac{25}{24}\\
&=\frac{119}{24}\approx 4.96.
\end{align*}

Comment: This is the correct value. I also got it through counting the combinations a different way. $E[X] = \sum_{n=1}^{6} n(n^3-(n-1)^3)/216 = 1071/216$

Comment: @ConnorJames. Cool. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Roll a die, each time we get an outcome value either 1,2,3,4,5 or 6.

Roll a die thrice, we get 3 outcome values.

For example the three outcomes could be first roll 3, second roll 5, third roll 1. Then the **largest** of the three outcomes is 5.

Indeed, the largest of the three coutcomes can be any of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6. Let's suppose they have **probabilities** $P_1$, $P_2$, $P_3$, $P_4$, $P_5$ and $P_6$.

So we want an expected value of this experiment.

The **expected value** is similar to the notion of average. To be accurate in our case it's

\begin{equation}
\text{Expected value} = 1\cdot P_1 + 2\cdot P_2 + .. + 6\cdot P_6
\end{equation}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).